# Aliexpress.com Scrapy Crawler localStorage.x5referer

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, session-cookies, aliexpress

I need to crawl [aliexpress](https://tr.aliexpress.com/af/sehpa.html?SearchText=sehpa) search result data related to my search keyword inputs.

Below my Scrapy code sample. I got localStorage.x5referer script in loging file. Maybe i need to handle some cookie things.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

class AliexpresSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'aliexpres'
    allowed_domains = ['aliexpress.com']
    start_urls = ['https://tr.aliexpress.com/af/sehpa.html?SearchText=sehpa']



    def parse(self,response):
        print(response.text)
        # srplists = response.css('ul.list-items')
        # for item in srplists.css('li.list-item'):
        #      title = item.css('div.item-title-wrap::text').get()
        #      price = item.css('div.item-price-wrap > span.price-big-sale::text').get()
        #      url = item.css('a ::attr(href)').get()
        #      yield {'title':title,'price':price,'url':url}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any findings on the topic ? I had the same problem there.

Comment: Hi, I didn't handle this with Scrapy. But you can try crawl Aliexpress with Selenium. Doc: [https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/]

Comment: Yes, but when crawling with selenium it's really slower than crawling without it. I guess this is the solution for now, maybe Aliexpress are catching the crawler somehow and redirecting to the login page. I'm using a proxy rotation and different user-agents, but every time I'm getting a redirection to login page and localStorage.x5referer script in the response.

Comment: did you guys find a solution?  I am trying to use scrapy to get localstorage.